# recursive algorithm's time usage

Tags: algorithm

i and my friend discussed following algorithm problem,

```
"Describe a recursive algorithm for finding the maximum element in an array A of n        
elements. What is your running time and space usage?"
```

we conclusioned that it has O(n) time usage. Accoriding to this statement, **F(n) =compare  A[n] with F(n-1)**, at base case of recursion, it compares A[0] and A[1], then returns bigger one, which will compare with A[2]. as recursion proceeds, finally in the end, it will return maximum element in an array.

each n time recursions, it compares only one time so finally we guessed it has O(n) time usage. 
my question is we aren't sure with our solution, so we want any other comments about this algorithm and our solution. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You approach for finding the time complexity is fine if the array contains `integers`. In case of numbers, comparing two numbers can be considered to be a unit operation. And while iterating over the array, to find the maximum value, this operations is performed `n` times. Hence `O(n)`.

But if the array contains complex datatypes, say `string`, then comparing two strings cannot be considered as a unit operation. To compare string you may have to iterate over each character of the string. In this case the time complexity of the algorithm may also start depending on the length of the strings in your array. Similarly for other datatypes, comparing two objects may not be a unit operation. But in your case, looks like the array contains numbers, so your are good.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you are correct, it is infact `O(n)`. How you can do quite simply is,

The basic operation of the algorithm is the comparison. And in step of the recursion the comparison is done only once.

So you can say

```
m(n) = m(n-1) + 1
m(n-1) = m(n-2) + 1 + 1
m(n-2) = m(n-3) + 2 + 1
```

generalizing we get

```
m(n-i) = m(n-1-i) + i + 1
```

now in your basecase, you would be doing no comparisons (basecase is no elements left, so you return the current largest). you can write this as

```
m(0) = 1
```

now substituting in the recurrence equation to get the base case, let `i = n-1`

we get

```
m(n) = m(0) + n - 1 + 1
```

but `m(0) = 0`

So we get

```
m(n) = n
```

Hence your algorithm is `O(n)`. There are other ways to prove this too. And even without a mathematical proof you can logically say your algorithm is `O(n)` since it does only one basic operation every recursive step, and the algorithm will always recurse n steps irrespective of the input.